# Making a Database search engine like Google

Tags: database, search-engine

I'm new to creating websites.I'm creating a Telephone directory search Engine.(Using PostgreSql,CGI scripts).My Database is having Name,Tel.No,City,State,Address.

Upto now I have created a search field like "google" where I can give any of the above Database entries and search.But now I want to give like "name+city+..." So that I can minimize the output entries.

Comment: How do you know whether the search string is name+city or city+name?  Seems like you're going to have to have a way for the user to identify what type of string she's typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you that you want to search all fields? Then:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE 
Name LIKE '%query%'
OR Tel.No LIKE '%query%'
OR City LIKE '%query%'
OR State LIKE '%query%'
OR Address LIKE '%query%'
```

Comment: Yes,actually I used it ,but in search if I give "name+city".How can it separate name and city and search them

Comment: my $Query="select name,telno from tel_dir where name like \'\%$FORM{'name'}\%\' or city like \'\%$FORM{'name'}\%\' or state like \'\%$FORM{'name'}\%\' or telno like \'\%$FORM{'name'}\%\';";

Comment: my $Query="select name,telno from tel_dir where name like \'\%$FORM{'name'}\%\' or city like \'\%$FORM{'name'}\%\' or state like \'\%$FORM{'name'}\%\' or telno like \'\%$FORM{'name'}\%\';";

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Silver Light's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438205/making-a-database-search-engine-like-google/4438263#4438263), you could use PostgreSQL's [multicolumn index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) to search for any or all of the fields inside a single index.

Answer (score 1):

I don't happen to know the programming language you are using but I can give you an idea about the algorithyou may use.
it is a simple one actually and contains many (if-conditions)

like the follwoing :

if (name is provided) => bring matching results and store them in Set1
if (city is provided) => filter the results in Set1 and get only the matching ones and store them in S2
if (address is provided) => filter the results in S2 and get only the matching ones and store them in S3 ...etc.

This way you take the whole set of phone records and filter it one time after another until you have it filtered completely , and whatever the user enters will bring him some results

I mean if you enter one field you will get plenty of results and if you enter two fields you will have less results beacuse the results will be filtered twice and if he entered three fields the results will be filtered triple times and so on...

in short words ... Just use Filtering
sorry for the long answer

Comment: But He can give any order like "name+state+city" or"city+state" or "Tel.No+city"......

Answer (score 0):

You can create the function where the WHERE clause can be created dynamically after checking which fields have been passed by the user to perform the search Query.